# Most efficient way to replace all values in a 2D integer numpy array with a three-element sub-array?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I've got a large 2D (N x N) numpy array containing integer values. I want to create from it a 3D array that is (N x N x 3), where -- in effect -- each integer in the original array is replaced by a three-element array containing a RGB triplet, based on a specific mapping from integer to RGB triplet.

As a scaled-down example, consider the input array

```
ints = np.array([[0, 1, 0, 2, 2],
                 [1, 1, 0, 2, 0],
                 [0, 0, 3, 0, 4],
                 [5, 0, 3, 0, 4],
                 [0, 3, 3, 0, 0]])
```

and a mapping from integers to RGB colors specified by

```
mapping = {0: [0, 0, 0],
           1: [255, 0, 0],
           2: [0, 255, 0],
           3: [0, 0, 255],
           4: [127, 127, 0],
           5: [127, 0, 127],
           6: [0, 127, 127]}
```

I would like an efficient (and, preferably, easy-to-read) method that would take `ints` and `mapping` and produce the output array

```
colors = np.array([[[0,0,0], [255,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,255,0], [0,255,0],],
                  [[255,0,0], [255,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,255,0], [0,0,0],],
                  [[0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,255], [0,0,0], [127,127,0],],
                  [[127,0,127], [0,0,0], [0,0,255], [0,0,0], [127,127,0],],
                  [[0,0,0], [0,0,255], [0,0,255], [0,0,0], [0,0,0],]])
```

I know I could allocate `colors` as an empty 3D array of the appropriate dimensions, and then loop over the rows and columns of `ints` and set the relevant slice of `colors` accordingly... But that seems super-inefficient, and my real arrays will be more like 1000 x 1000. Does anyone have suggestions for faster, more elegant, more idiomatic approaches?

(FYI, my motivation is to use plotly's `imshow` method to create a visualization of the matrix, like a heatmap, but with optimally distinct colors for the different numbers rather than any kind of continuum like the standard coloration options assume.)

Answer (score 1):

Since your map key can be integers, the mapping can be the same as indexing, and the RGB values can just be a Nx3 array.

Something like this:

```
x =  np.arange(30).reshape((10,3))  # the map

keys = np.array([1, 4, 7, 3])

x[keys] # the mapping

# which gives
array([[ 3,  4,  5],
       [12, 13, 14],
       [21, 22, 23],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])
```

Comment: Interesting… I just tried this with a 2D array for `keys`, and it seems to work!

Answer (score 0):

Make a (7,3) array with

```
arr = np.array(list(mapping.values()))
```

index it with

```
arr[idx,:]
```

That depends on `mapping` being ordered and complete.